# Removing elements from array where first letter matches character

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is an angular 1 app.
I have an array that looks like this:

```
var my_arr = [
    {key: 'KEY1', label: 'label1'},
    {key: 'KEY2', label: 'label2'},
    {key: 'KEY3', label: '#label3'}
];
```

I need to remove the items where the label begins with hashtag.
Is there a way to do this with one liner? Or at least without manually looping the array?

*****EDIT*****

Basically, I need (in the example above) remove the item labelled "#label3" as it begins with hashtag (#).

Comment: Is it `var my arr` or `var my_arr`?

Comment: sorry, editet now.

Comment: Your question is really unclear what you are actually asking. So you want it to be just the key1, and key2 lines after the code runs? If yes, learn to use `filter()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var myArr = [
    {key: 'KEY1', label: 'label1'}
    ,{key: 'KEY2', label: 'label2'}
    ,{key: 'KEY3', label: '#label3'}
];

var results = myArr.filter(item => !item.label.startsWith('#'));

console.log(results);
```

Comment: More elegant than `label[0]!=='#'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.filter` and in the callback you can have a condition which checks if the label starts with a hashtag of not.

```js
var my_arr = [
    {key: 'KEY1', label: 'label1'}
    ,{key: 'KEY2', label: 'label2'}
    ,{key: 'KEY3', label: '#label3'}
];

my_arr = my_arr.filter(el=> el.label[0]!=='#');

console.log(my_arr);
```